# Two Lagrangian submanifolds with clean intersections

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, holomorphic-symplectic

Having two closed exact Lagrangian submanifolds $L_1$ and $L_2$ that intersect cleanly inside a Liouville manifold $M$ with $c_1(M)=0,$ is there (with possibly some other conditions) any relation between $$H^*(L_1 \cap L_2)$$ and $$HF^*(L_1,L_2)?$$ In particular, (when) are they necessarily isomorphic?

Comment: The intersection $L_1\cap L_2$  is zero dimensional so there is no cohomology in positive degrees.

Comment: Not necessarily. I didn't say they intersect transversely.

Comment: You can see work of Abouzaid  https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.1474 for more refined statements about the Fukaya category generated by L_1,L_2.

Comment: Great, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a spectral sequence from the cohomology of the intersection to the Floer cohomology. This is explained (and used) in Seidel's paper "Lagrangian 2-spheres can be symplectically knotted"

https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9803083

and is based on the thesis of Pozniak, available here:

http://www.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/Pozniak.pdf

(As far as I remember, Pozniak didn't mention the spectral sequence, but it's one way of understanding his work).

Edit: In particular, to answer your last question, if the Lagrangians are exact and the intersection is connected then the spectral sequence degenerates at $E_2$ and the Floer cohomology is isomorphic to the cohomology of the intersection. If there are J-holomorphic discs (e.g. potentially when the Lagrangians are non-exact) then this might not be true. The example to bear in mind is $L_1=L_2$: the intersection is connected, and we have $HF(L,L)=H(L)$ whenever L is exact, but not in general.

Comment: Thanks! And just to clarify: for this spectral sequence to exist, you need $L_1$ and $L_2$ to intersect cleanly?

Comment: Yes, sorry: I assumed you wanted that from the title of the question, but it's definitely worth stressing! The columns of the E_2 page are the cohomology groups of the components of the intersection (shifted vertically in some way that I can't recall).

Comment: In addition, as Seidel explains in that paper, when $H^1(L_1)=H^1(L_2)=0,$ the Floer cohomology $HF^*(L_1,L_2)$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-graded, where the grading is defined up to a shift. Is there any canonical way to choose this shift, under some special conditions on the ambient and Lagrangians? Ideally, getting the isomorphism $H^*(L_1,L_2) \cong H^*(L_1 \cap L_2)$ without a shift?

Comment: If you pick gradings on L_1 and L_2 independently then you can just adjust the grading on one of them to shift the grading on HF(L_1,L_2) however you like.

Comment: Thanks! indeed my question doesn't make sense on its own. 
(I was thinking about a collection of Lagrangians $L_1,\dots, L_n$ and the Floer product in the algebra $\oplus_{i,j} HF^*(L_i, L_j)$ but that's another topic).

Comment: Incidentally, it seems to me that the isomorphism $HF(L,L) \cong H(L)$ for an exact Lagrangian cannot be stated with $\mathbb{Z}$-gradings unless $L$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-graded (which for example happens when $H^1(L,\mathbb{Z})=0$). Is this correct?

Comment: It's true that the grading on HF doesn't make sense unless L is graded... But then again, if you use the pearl model for HF, the Floer differential equals the Morse differential (there are no discs), so in some sense there is a Z grading (all pearly trajectories increase Morse index by 1).

Comment: Right, that makes sense.